# Mailgun webhook incoming payload is empty

Tags: codeigniter, webhooks, mailgun, payload

I try to get payload from **mailgun webhook** in Codeignaiter but all these are empty.

```
function index($payload = '')
{
        var_dump($_POST); // empty
        var_dump($_GET); // empty
        var_dump($payload); // empty
}
```

I test my webhook url from mailgun dashboard , it is ok  and it works but with empty payload.

```
Response: array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
string(0) ""
```

But when test with **Postbin** it returns data like this

```
{
  "timestamp": "1602575614",
  "token": "3d21344bf13e4999bc6233a2031984f5ed4a7d9b5a42df9189",
  "signature": "b1269faef2b44ce7f1ceaada83838691ed00203d1eb228e9c7097b7ec725a19c"
}
...
```

What can be a reason of empty data ?

Comment: Is  your CSRF protection active? If you're getting POSTed without the correct CSRF token (which is something an external provider will never have) you should (CAREFULLY) move to `php://input`, which opens a whole different can of worms, or add an exception on the CSRF protection on the specific controller/method pair that's supposed to receive the data from mailgun's webhook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will return data I need

```
$postedData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
print_r($postedData);
```